# How can I use a directory name with non-ASCII chars in VS Code and Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I can not use Visual Studio Code app because when I write my codes and click to run button, I get an error. I think the error relevant with my computer user name which is not 'HUAWEI', but 'HUAWEİ'. VS Code can't read the file name because of the 'İ' word. It read 'HUAWEİ' as 'HUAWE', and here is my error:

PS C:\Users\HUAWEİ\Desktop\python> & C:/Users/**HUAWE**/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/Users/**HUAWE**/Desktop/python/Hello_World.py
& : The term 'C:/Users/**HUAWE**/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Che
ck the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:3

- & C:/Users/**HUAWE**/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c: ...
- ```
  + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:/Users/HUAWE/...on39/python.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Answer (score -1):

To change the name of the file that you are editing.
Follow the steps:
1.Right click on the file in the right side.
2.Look for an option called rename.
3.Click on rename and rename it and press enter.

Comment: The problem is not about the file that I am editing. The problem is about the location of my file. It is in C:/Users/HUAWEİ folder and it can not be changed, because it is my computer's user directory.